# dojo 1.8: Remotely update content pane from other content pane by widgets

Tags: ajax, dojo

Hi do you have any idea how I can update in content pane from other content pane remotely? 
ie html update in one contentpane and change one part in other contentpane by ajax...
Are there any examples or tutorials for me.

Thanks 
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try this tutorial you might get an idea from it.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/TextBox.html#getting-and-manipulating-the-value

Then let try more example about dijit/registry.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry

Comment: Hi Sthpuan, It seems that I am not able to load dojo file into contentpane. When the dojo file is parsed correctly, It seems that it is not parsed properly in the contentpane. Please advise. Clement

Comment: Could you give me your code example (It can be a pseudo one) since I'm not sure what did you exactly mean for 'dojo file'.